# Is there Rich Media Support for iPhone Applications ?

Tags: ios4, xcode4

Is there Rich Media Support API  for iPhone Applications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "rich media" is commonly used to describe "a broad range of digital interactive media" . For up to date view of available (built-in) support for audio/video formats and related technologies available to developers of iOS (iPhone) applications check out:
https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/audio-and-video.html

Kind regards,
Bo